# Changing the value of a variable inside page.evaluate Puppeteer (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm relatively new to this so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a web scraper with Puppeteer and I have the following code:

```
var data = [];

async function scrapePage (url, data) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    var dataPup = await page.evaluate( (url, data) => {

        data.push("example")

        return {
            "Data": data,
        }

    }, url, data);

    await console.log({
        "Data": dataPup,
        "Data Check": data,
    });

    await browser.close();
    return;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when logging "Data" and "Data Check" to the console, the changes made to the data variable don't change outside of dataPup. Is there a way to make changes inside of dataPup update variables globally? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this I found a workaround. It's a bit sloppy if you have a large number of variables, but it gets the job done so if anyone knows of a cleaner way to do this please let me know. Adding the following line before logging the data to the console will save the data to the global variable data:

```
data += dataPup["Data"];
```

After that you just log data instead of dataPup to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access that with window.data, otherwise it's out of scope.